# Why doesn't numpy.unique recognize that multiple numpy.nan values are identical?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a short example script:

```py
import numpy as np

print('numpy version:       ', np.version.version)

foo = np.full(10, 5)
bar = np.full(10, np.nan)

print('foo:                 ', foo)
print('Unique values of foo:', np.unique(foo))

print('bar:                 ', bar)
print('Unique values of bar:', np.unique(bar))
```

It prints the following result:

```
numpy version:        1.16.4
foo:                  [5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5]
Unique values of foo: [5]
bar:                  [nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan]
Unique values of bar: [nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan]
```

**My questions:**

1. Why doesn't `np.unique()` return just a single `nan` value when it receives `bar` as input?  Surely this is an error, right?  Or if it's the correct, expected behavior, then why is it correct?
2. What is the recommended workaround--if any--for obtaining the more typical behavior as illustrated by `foo`?

Answer (score 7):

To answer your question why: the IEEE spec ([IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754)) for floating point numbers, which is how numpy [defines NaN](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/constants.html#numpy.NAN) is not equal to anything including itself. Numpy is respecting this, which is why `np.nan == np.nan` is false.

People complain about this, but it's a hard choice to make because NaN can arise from things that are not equal. For example, should this expression be true?

```
np.sqrt(-1) == np.sqrt(-2)
```

Both evaluate to NaN, but saying the above should be true seems very wrong. *You* need to decide how to handle NaN in your code—if your want to treat them all the same way, you certainly can.

Answer (score 2):

**First question:**

As you can see:

```
>>> np.nan == np.nan
False
>>>
```

`np.nan`s don't equal each other.

**Second question:**

It can't be pretty, only way that I can think of is:

```
>>> a = np.unique(np.where(np.isnan(bar), 0, bar))
>>> np.where(a == 0, np.nan, a)
array([ nan])
>>>
```

Comment: I like your workaround, although of course it seems like it would get a slightly incorrect result if `bar` included any `0` values in addition to the `nan`s.  But at least it could be made to work in most situations.

Comment: @stachyra Yeah `NaN`s are not easy to deal with

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I can fully recommend it, but if sort order of unique elements doesn't matter:

```
# make example with nans                                                                                                    
x = np.arange(15)%5-2                                                                                       
y = x.astype(bool)/x                                                       
y                                                                                                           
# array([-0.5, -1. ,  nan,  1. ,  0.5, -0.5, -1. ,  nan,  1. ,  0.5, -0.5,                                        
#        -1. ,  nan,  1. ,  0.5])

# trick comes here                                                                                 
np.unique(y.view(int)).view(float)
# array([-0.5, -1. ,  nan,  0.5,  1. ])
```

Be warned, though, that this map between int and float is not 100% one-to-one, for example:

```
(np.array(np.nan).view(int)+1).view(float)
# nan
```

This last nan would compare not equal to a standard nan even when we applied the cast-to-int-and-back trick.